# Can a compound with indirectly bonded carbon and silicon atoms within the same aromatic system be called organosilicon compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, terminology

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organosilicon) says that organosilicon compounds are organic compounds with carbon-silicon bonds.

Does the class of organosilicon compounds include compounds in which the carbon and silicon are only indirectly bonded, for example the (hypothetical) molecule 1,3,5-trihydroxy-4,6-dioxa-2-lambda3-oxa-3,5-disilacyclohex-1-ene(3+), in which the carbon and silicon atoms are not formally directly bonded but are part of the same aromatic (six π-electrons) ring, sharing the same aromatic bonding orbitals?

[Here's what the molecule looks like (direct uploadd won't work for some reason...)](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnbXjD7kMdR9pVkIFRPEf0ifFlol)

Comment: Is there the possibility to include a picture of this hypothetical compound. Not all of us might be familiar with this type of naming scheme. (Yes, I really have not a single clue, what this compound might look like.)

Answer (score 1):

Organosilicon compounds fall under the broader category of [Organometallic compounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organometallic_chemistry). It is a requirement that in organometallic compounds, **atleast one $\ce{C-M}$ bond should exist**. Since Si is only bonded to oxygen atoms in your compound, the given compound is not an organosilicon compound.

The following is also mentioned in the wikipedia page for [Organosilicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organosilicon) compounds, under the image:

> A carbon–silicon bond present in all organosilicon compounds